# MySQL update performance VERY bad

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I'm having VERY bad performance with UPDATE on MySQL, my update statement is quite basic like:

```
UPDATE `tbl_name` 
   SET `field1` = 'value1', `field2` = 'value2' .. `fieldN` = 'valueN' 
WHERE `tbl_name`.`id` = 123;
```

values are few (15), all TEXT kind and WHERE condition is just one using id.
values are JSON strings (but this should not bother to MySQL, it should see them as just plain text).

In "tbl_name" I have few records (around 4k).

The problem is that executing this UPDATE statement I got 8 seconds of execution time (taken from MySQL slow query log).

I'm running MySQL alone on an EC2 High CPU Medium istance and I think it's pretty impossible that these performances are "normal", I would expect much more performance.

Do you have any idea to investigate the problem?

** UPDATE **
Thank you for your fast answers, table is InnoDB and id is a PRIMARY, UNIQUE. Values are TEXT (not varchar)

** UPDATE bis **
No, id is an integer, all other fields are TEXT

Comment: I suppose you have an index for the id column? If you could paste the CREATE script for that table it would be great.

Comment: Did you create an UNIQUE key on your table ? Is the "ID" field, a PRIMARY key in AUTOINCREMENT ? Can you please specify the database type fields ? Are they in "TEXT" or "VARCHAR" ?

Comment: have u set indexing for id column ?

Comment: @LaurentBrieu `AUTO_INCREMENT` is irrelevant to update performance, only the index matters.

Comment: You right @Ianzz, there's no direct impact on performance in this case

Comment: "*all TEXT kind*"?  Including `id`?

Comment: Show us the CREATE TABLE statement for that table

Comment: I am not an expert on AWS, but: Are both the volume of the DB and the runing instance of mysql on the same AWS datacenter?

Comment: are you, in the SET expression, updating the id?

Answer (score 1):

Since MySQL do not support `EXPLAIN UPDATE` statements before version 5.6.3, we're quite blind about this query. Try `USE INDEX` statement...

I've launched the same on my server. All was ok with 15 `TEXT` fields and 4096 rows of quite arbitrary text. It was ok with both `USE INDEX(PRIMARY)` and `IGNORE INDEX(PRIMARY)` statements.

So, I suppose, you have problems with your SQL server, installation package, or whatever, not query...